# Is there a way to select code between certain characters

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-code

**TL DR**

Is there some extension, or other functionality, to select code above and below the cursor that is surrounded by some characters, e.g. `%%` or `% =====` or anything else?

**Why**

I am coding Matlab in VSCode, since the builtin Matlab editor lacks a lot of useful functionalities. However, One thing that I miss is the ability to run 'sections':

```
%% section 1
x = 0:0.01:pi;
y = sin(y);
plot(x,y);

%% section 2
x = 0:0.01:pi;
y = cos(y);
plot(x,y);

%% section 3
x = 0:0.01:pi;
y = tan(y);
plot(x,y);
```

A section can be run using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Since I use Matlab on Windows, there is no support for running the Matlab interpreter from the terminal/cmd.

So I created some AutoHotKey scripts that will copy selected code, open the Matlab window, paste it, and run. This works fine, however, when I want to run a very large section, this means that I have to select this manually, and press my defined shortcut to call the AutoHotkey script. Hence above question.

So say I have the cursor at some line in`section 2`, how can I select only the code in this section (including or excluding section 'headers', these are comments so does not matter).

Comment: You cannot do this to the best of my knowledge, however using control + arrow(s) to move around and shift + control + arrow(s) makes text selection quick (but this is just general editing of course!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made an extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) that allows the selection based on regular expressions relative to the cursor position. You can specify different expressions for forward and backward search and if you want to include the searched text in the selection.

You can set up to 5 regex searches.

The extension defines 5 commands that can be used in keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Awesome! Is it possible to add an option to copy the selection to clipboard per regex  e.g. as option `"copyToClipboard"`. I feel a bit ungrateful for asking, but unfortunately I have no experience with writing JS nor vscode extensions myself...

Comment: @rinkert I will add this option

Comment: @rinkert v0.3.0 contains the copyToClipboard option, look at the known issues. I will create an issue on the vscode github repo about this.

Answer (score 2):

This can (of course) be done by writing a custom extension.

Since this seems like useful functionality in general and an interesting exercise, I've added the required capability to my personal [vscode-smcpeak](https://github.com/smcpeak/vscode-smcpeak) extension.

To use it:

1. Install [vscode-smcpeak](https://github.com/smcpeak/vscode-smcpeak/releases).  This has to be installed [manually](https://github.com/smcpeak/vscode-smcpeak/blob/master/README.md#installation) for now.  At time of writing, 0.0.7 is latest.
2. Install [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ctf0.macros) by **ctf0**.  This one can be installed from within VSCode.  **Restart VSCode after installing it.**  (See below regarding the choice of "macros" extension.)
3. Add to your `settings.json` (File → Preferences → Settings, then click the "Open Settings (JSON)" icon in the upper right):

```
    // Custom macros for ctf0.macros extension
    "macros.list": {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57749780/is-there-a-way-to-select-code-between-certain-characters
        "selectPercentRegion": [
            {
                "command": "smcpeak.goToLineMatching",
                "args": {
                    "regex": "^%%",
                    "moveUp": true,
                    "select": false,
                    "allowZeroMove": true
                }
            },
            {
                "command": "smcpeak.goToLineMatching",
                "args": {
                    "regex": "^%%",
                    "moveUp": false,
                    "select": true,
                    "allowZeroMove": false
                }
            },
            "smcpeak.revealCurrentSelection"
        ]
    },
```

4. Add to `keybindings.json` (File → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts, then click the "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" icon in the upper right):

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+m",   // or whatever
        "command": "macros.selectPercentRegion"
    },
```

(Note: VSCode will always complain that `macros.selectPercentRegion` is not a valid command.  That's a limitation of the "macros" extension.)

Then, with the cursor within a region delimited by the specified regexes, press the keybinding to activate the macro:

[image: Screenshot of before and after macro invocation]

### Why use two extensions?

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57751509/2659307), by rioV8 uses a single extension to answer the OP's question.  This looks like a good solution to me, and is simpler to use than mine, so I approve of that being the accepted answer.

However, there is an advantage to my approach: it allows the behavior to be modified in `settings.json`.  For example, the OP asked in a follow-up question about having the command additionally copy the text to the clipboard after selecting.  Using the macro-based solution, this is an easy modification to `settings.json`; simply add:

```
            "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction"
```

to the end of the `selectPercentRegion` macro.  (That is the command normally bound to Ctrl+C.)

Thus, while my suggestion has more moving parts, I personally prefer this approach.

### Which macros extension to use?

As Mark noted in a comment, the most popular macros extension, [geddski.macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros), is unmaintained.  It furthermore has a rather serious [bug](https://github.com/geddski/macros/pull/11) in that the commands are not properly sequenced, leading to race conditions.  (I actually saw this once during my testing.)

There are two forks of geddski.macros on the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode), [l7ssha.macrosRe](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=l7ssha.macrosRe) and [ctf0.macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ctf0.macros).  l7ssha.macrosRe only adds the ["delay" ability](https://github.com/geddski/macros/pull/13), which is an awkward way to resolve the race conditions.  ctf0.macros, on the other hand, fully fixes the race condition (via a [complete rewrite](https://github.com/ctf0/macros/commit/4157aed8366e13b1a7f04cbd2591c0dd95a5ec61)).

Therefore, I recommend **ctf0.macros**, and in fact have edited my answer to use it rather than the original geddski.macros extension.

However, be aware:

- ctf0.macros uses `macros.list` rather than `macros` in `settings.json`
- ctf0.macros requires a restart of VSCode after installation to activate

### How it works

The additions are in [vscode-smcpeak commit 6d5f5d4689](https://github.com/smcpeak/vscode-smcpeak/commit/6d5f5d4689b245dd4ec722d12fddc34449c91759).

My extension registers a new command, `smcpeak.goToLineMatching`, that searches up or down for a line containing a regex.  The logic is very simple, just a loop and regex test.

It also registers `smcpeak.revealCurrentSelection`, needed because otherwise the selected text might be offscreen and nothing scrolls to it by default.

The macro `selectPercentRegion` uses `goToLineMatching` to look upwards for one regex, setting the anchor (selection start) there, then uses it again to look down for another regex (although they are the same here), extending the selection to that point.  Then it scrolls to ensure the selection is visible.

It should be straightforward to transplant this code to your own extension if you don't want the rest of the stuff that mine provides.  (But mine does not bind any keys, so there should be no downside to having the extra stuff.)

Comment: Just as an aside, if you look at the issues and PRs for the `macros` extension, it isn't being maintained well.  I would consider another macro extension.

Comment: @Mark Yes, I saw that.  There are a couple forks, but none is nearly as popular as the original so far.  Also the forks are generally maintaining backward compatibility, so there is reason to be hopeful that we'll see a proper successor that won't require changing the `macros` definitions.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I went with the other answer since that does not need the macro extension, but awesome job! +1

Comment: @Mark I've reconsidered and decided that you're right.  I've edited my answer to use ctf0.macros instead of geddski.macros.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this, with an extension I wrote [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview).

Make this keybinding in your `keybindings.json` (or it could be a setting too):

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",                   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "^(%%[\\s\\S]+?)(?=^$)|(^%%[\\s\\S]+)",
    "run": [
      "$${",
        "const sections = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selections;",
        "await vscode.commands.executeCommand('cursorUndo');",
        
        "const mySection = sections.find(section => section.contains(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection));",
        "if (mySection) {",
          "vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selections = [mySection];"
        "}",
        
      "}$$",
    ],

    "isRegex": true,
    "postCommands": "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction"
  }
}
```

The find regex finds and selects all `%% ....` sections.  But since you only want the section where your cursor started, some code is `run` to restore that original cursor and then find that section that contains the one current cursor.  Then that section is selected.  And in the `postCommand` that selection is saved to the clipboard.

That is using javascript and the vscode extension api within a keybinding or setting.

[image: select text around the cursor]